# Background color having rounded edges

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal as given below.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title"><b>Outage Details</b></h4>
        </div>
```

I'm trying to change the background color of the modal header using the given CSS

```
.modal-header
{
    background-color : #0063C3
}
```

It is working fine, but the color is not filling completely up to the edges. You can see white color on the edges. Screenshot below for reference. How can we fill the modal header completely with the background color.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr7wa.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `rounded-0` utility class to remove the rounded corners..

```
   <div class="modal-header rounded-0">
         <h4 class="modal-title"><b>Outage Details</b></h4>
   </div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/XHvAXID48s

Answer (score 0):

That may be as a result of `border-radius`. Try removing the `border-radius` like so

```
.modal-header
{
    background-color : #0063C3;
    border-radius:0!important;
}
```

Comment: While this answer indeed fixed the problen i want to point out that using css `!important` is _never_ good, its always a workaround. In general i suggest avoiding `!important` at all cost. Still there are some cases youll need it in some cases e.g. overwriting inline styles from javascript you cant change, but generally speaking a healty approach imo is to stay away as far as you can from `!important` and just use proper cascading.